# Is this proof of convergence in $\ell_p$ vaild?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\{x_{n,i} \}$ be a Cauchey seq. of sequences in $(\ell^{p},d_{p})$ ,
$ \ell^{p}=
 \{  \{x_{n} \} ;  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid {x_n} \mid ^{p} < \infty  \} $.
Show

\begin{equation*}
\lim_i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid \{x_{n,i}\} - \{y_n\} \mid ^{p}=0
\end{equation*} if $\{y_n\}$ is the "pointwise" limit.

Since $\{\{x_n\}_i\}$ is Cauchy pick $K$ s.t for all $i,j > K , j>i$ 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid \{x_{n,i}\} - \{x_{n,j}\} \mid ^{p} < \epsilon
\end{equation*}
This K hold for all n in particular  $n> N$ for some $N$. Now pick largest $J>K$ such that  $\mid \{\{x_n,j\}\} - \{y_n\} \mid < \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}}$ for all $n$ in particualr $n > M \ge N$. Hence
\begin{equation*}
\lim_i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid \{x_{n,i}\} - \{y_n\} \mid ^{p} \le \lim_i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid \{x_{n,i}\} - \{x_{n,j}\} \mid ^{p} +\lim_i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid \{x_{n,j}\} - \{y_n\} \mid ^{p} \le 2\epsilon
\end{equation*}
for all $i>J$. I seen some other proofs which are vaild and according to me are equivalent. But I dont feel $100$ % confident. This looks to easy, what do I miss?

Comment: What's $\ell_p$?

Comment: @AlecTeal the set of all p-summable seqeunces $p\in [1,\infty)$

Comment: Please clarify $p$-summable. (I like to check that the notation is standard) then I'll take a look at your proof :)

Comment: @AlecTeal sequences for which the sum of the modulus to the pth power of every element is finite

Comment: Can we use the completeness of the space $\ell_p$? Or is this a part of the proof that $\ell_p$ is complete?

Comment: @Tzakrevskiy this is the last step in proving that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a problem with picking the $J$.
Consider for example the sequence defined by $x_{n,i} = \delta_{i,n} 2^{-n+1}$. Then we have $$\lim_{i,j \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_{n,i}-x_{n,j}|^p = \lim_{i,j \to \infty} 2^{-pi+p}+2^{-pj+p} = 0,$$ so we have a Cauchy sequence, with pointwise limit $0$.
Now you want to find a $J$ such that $|x_{n,J}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ for all $n$, however, for all $j$ we have $|x_{j,j}| = \frac{2}{2^j}$, so for any $\epsilon \le2$ we cannot find such a $J$, and for any $\epsilon > 2$ there is no largest $J$.